# Python Scrapy - Form Action behaves differently in browser, no redirect

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, struts

I'm developing a Scrapy project to scrape information from [Wisconsin's Circuit Court Access](http://wcca.wicourts.gov/) program for the law firm I work with. I'm able to get to the Advanced Search Page which I'm filling using the FormRequest.from_response() method, but the response is the search page with the fields filled in and a URL matching the form action /caseSearchResults.do (I'm leaving off the JSESSIONID and other fields for simplicty's sake)

If I open the site in a web browser, /caseSearchResults.do will 302 redirect me to /pager.do which has the list of case search results I need to crawl to scrape the date from.  The problem is no matter what I try I don't get the redirect.  I've changed the user agent string, added all of the form fields to formdata, added a delay between requests, tried a single request per session, and nothing changes the behavior.

One thing to note is that the behavior is similar, but not identical, to what happens when you don't fill enough fields for a search in a browser.  In that case it also sends you to /caseSearchResults.do with the search form, just as it does for my scrapy requests, however it adds an error message to the HTML that does not appear in the scrapy response.

I did some digging and it seems like this site is running Apache Struts? I haven't found any advice on crawling .do pages, so maybe this is an obscure use-case. I'd really like to know whether this is something I'm doing wrong on my end or if I'm getting flagged as a bot and served a dead-end page.

Here's my spider:

```
import scrapy, datetime
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class ccapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ccapSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['wicourts.gov']
    start_urls = ['http://wcca.wicourts.gov/index.xsl']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, callback=self.parse2, formnumber=1)

    def parse2(self, response):
        returnedList = response.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "caseSearchSelect")]/@href').extract()
        url = 'http://wcca.wicourts.gov/' + returnedList[0]
        return  scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse3)

    def parse3(self, response):
        countyList = ['3', '6', '7', '9', '10', '17', '18', '27', '46', '47', '48', '50', '54', '55', '57', '60', '61', '65']
        today = datetime.date.today()
        startDate = today - datetime.timedelta(days=11)
        dateString = startDate.strftime('%x')
        for county in countyList:
                yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, callback=self.parseResults, clickdata={'value' : 'Search'}, formdata={'countyNo' : county, 'caseType'     : 'CV,SC', 'filingDate.dateString' : dateString, 'filingDateRange' : '5', 'recordsPerPage' : '50', 'partyName.showMissingMiddleNames' : 'true', 'partyDateOfBirth.orN    ull' : 'true', 'dispoDateRange' : '1', 'lastModifiedDateRange' : '1', 'documentsAddedDateRange' : '1', 'attyNoType' : 'partyAtty', 'offenseDateRange' : '1', 'partyNam    e.lastName' : '', 'partyName.firstName' : '', 'partyName.middleName' : '', 'partyDateOfBirth.dateString' : '', 'partyName.businessName' : '', 'caseRange.year' : '', '    caseRange.caseType' : '', 'caseRange.start' : '', 'caseRange.end' : '', 'statusCode' : '', 'dispoDate.dateString' : '', 'lastModifiedDate.dateString' : '', 'documents    AddedDate.dateString' : '', 'wcisClsCode' : '', 'oldCaseNo' : '', 'attyNo' : '', 'citnNo' : '', 'arrestTrackingNo' : '', 'justisNo' : '', 'ncicAgencyId' : '', 'daCase    No' : '', 'offenseDate.dateString' : '', 'prosAtty' : '', 'issAgencyNo' : '', 'showCountyLists' : 'Get a List of Prosecuting Attorneys by County', 'showCountyLists' :     'Get a List of Agencies by County'})

    def parseResults(self, response):
        caseDetailPages = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "caseDetails")]/@href').extract()
        urls = []
        for page in caseDetailPages:
            urls.append('http://wcca.wicourts.gov/' + page)
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parseCaseDetails)
        nextPageList = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "offset=50")]/@href').extract()
        if nextPageList:
            nextPage = 'http://wcca.wicourts.gov/' + nextPageList[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(nextPage, callback=self.parsePage2)
```

Edit: I've determined that FormRequest is clicking buttons for me inappropriately that return me to a version of the search page with an expanded select box. There's also a javascript snippet in the page with comments referring to the button:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  // In order to get the enter key to submit the search button
  // all submit buttons above the search button need to
  // 1. be changed to type="button"
  // 2. have a corresponding disabled hidden input
  // 3. call this function onClick to enable the corresponding hidden input
  function submitBtn(classToEnable){
      //alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
      $("." + classToEnable).removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#caseSearch").submit();
    }
  </script>
```

Here are the offending buttons in the source before:

```
<INPUT class="formField" type="hidden" name="prosAtty" value=""> 
<INPUT class="formField" type="button" name="showCountyLists" value="Get a List of Prosecuting Attorneys by County" onclick="submitBtn('prosAttyListInitial')">
<input type="hidden" name="showCountyLists" class="prosAttyListInitial" value="Get a List of Prosecuting Attorneys by County" disabled="disabled">

<INPUT class="formField" type="hidden" name="issAgencyNo" value="">   
<INPUT class="formField" type="button" name="showCountyLists" value="Get a List of Agencies by County" onclick="submitBtn('agencyListInitial')">
<input type="hidden" name="showCountyLists" class="agencyListInitial" value="Get a List of Agencies by County" disabled="disabled">
```

And in the response:

```
              <SELECT class="formField" name="prosAtty">
                <OPTION class="formField" value="" selected="selected"></OPTION><OPTION class="formField" value="1000632">Alfredson, Patricia K. </OPTION>
                <OPTION class="formField" value="1023815">Altman, Elizabeth  </OPTION>
                <snip/>
                <OPTION class="formField" value="801">UWS</OPTION>
                <OPTION class="formField" value="311">Zoning Commission</OPTION>
              </SELECT><BR><INPUT class="formField" type="button" name="showCountyLists" value="Reload List" onclick="submitBtn('agencyListReload')"><input type="hidden" name="showCountyLists" class="agencyListReload" value="Reload List" disabled="disabled">
```

And the button I actually want clicked:

```
<INPUT class="formField" TYPE="submit" name="formAction" value="Search"/>
```

Do I need to specify every attribute in the clickdata parameter?  I've tried it with both dont_click=True and clickdata={'value' : 'Search'} and it behaves in the same way.  Could this be a problem with FormResponse handling the hidden fields?

Comment: Could you please remove the line numbers from the code? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `cookiejar` meta key for the FormRequests? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-cookiejar

Comment: @elias I added the cookiejar in where I yielded the FormRequests in parse3 using county as an index.  It didn't solve the problem so I removed it.  Perhaps I should add it when it first requests its cookie in the first FormRequest? One thing I just noticed is that at the second  FormRequest it adds a chacheId to the Url, maybe that's related? I think I tried it with a single search request, but I didn't document everything I tried.  Wouldn't a single request work if cookies were the problem, or does the cookiejar do something the automatic cookie handling doesn't do for a single iteration?

Comment: @BradyEklund I'm not sure if only enforcing single request would work, because the order of the requests is not guaranteed (eg, it can do two FormRequest before doing the request to attend the first FR). So, if the problem is really the app storing state in the server's session (what I suspect), the cookiejar would be the way to go. Btw, it's not enough only adding in the FormRequests, you also have to repass the cookiejar value from response.meta for the subsequent requests.

Comment: @elias After looking at the HTML response I found there are some buttons being clicked even though I have either click_data, dont_click, or both set on the .from_response call.  I found some comments in a javascript snippet and the code for the offending buttons which I'll post in an edit to my initial question.